# C++: Dump RAM contents

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

- How can I achieve that without triggering an access violation?

I have tried having a bool pointer set to a specific start location and then incrementing it step by step. This results in an access violation.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: I'm curious :) Also getting into security topics, e.g. manipulating code of running programs

Comment: That question makes no sense. In Win32, your process is always assigned __4GB of virtual memory__. Not all of these 4GB is backed up by hardware (obviously, since Win32 can't access more than 4GB total, and there's more running than just your process). Half of you process' memory is reserved for OS stuff and mustn't be accessed by your code.

Comment: On Linux, it would be `kill -6` (while having coredumps enabled of course).

Answer (score 9):

Windows is a virtual memory operating system. Which means that software deals with "memory" - which may, or may not, be cached in RAM at some point in time. Quite a lot of a processes memory is probably stored on disk - in the pagefile, or as part of a file mapping.

So then, if you downgrade from "dumping RAM" to "dumping memory", then you need to ask yourself "which memory".

In addition to being a virtual memory OS, Windows also protects applications from each other - each process gets their own private address space for memory. So, you need to decide what memory you want to dump. our own process? Thats easy. Use VirtualQuery to examine the blocks and dump them out.

Looking at another process? Thats more complicated. There are security barriers that prevent untrusted applications from looking into more trusted processes memory. VirtualQueryEx will let you examine another process if you have sufficient rights.

Finally, if you want to examine the kernel memory, then you need to develop some kind of driver: Usermode code is not allowed to look at kernel memory at all.

Comment: `+1` for a nice, comprehensive answer to a very confused question.

Answer (score 1):

It's OS specific. For windows you can use `VirtualQuery()` to obtain the map of "readable" memory pages.

Comment: How do buffer overflows work then without crashing the program immediately? For example javascript string exploits

Comment: @Lederp: That's a totally different question, only loosely related to your original one.

Comment: @Lederp: In the memory space of your process are many other things. If you know how or where to find them, there will be no crash. It's one of the reasons ASLR was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dump file using [MiniDumpWriteDump()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680360%28VS.85%29.aspx), and explore that since you'e just curious.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @John's answer, if you want to inspect the memory and other state of a running process, you really have to learn about [the DbgHelp API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679309%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  This is a non-trivial endeavour, essentially you are writing your own debugger.

A simple minidump as John suggested would be a good start, not requiring the same amount of effort, but which would allow you to inspect a snapshot of the process state.